# How to create image in virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, virtualbox

I am running Mac. I installed recently VirtualBox to run an Ubuntu distro. I configured Ubuntu in VirtualbBox and installed all the software I need. Now I want to make it available to some colleagues who just want to avoid repeating the same installation process.

What I want is to create an image which they can simply import into their Virtualbox instance.

IS that possible? I have this:

```
$ ls -ltr
total 17610800
-rw-------+ 1 fran  staff        8317 Sep 24 21:30 Ubuntu.vbox-prev
drwx------+ 6 fran  staff         204 Sep 24 21:32 Logs
-rw-------+ 1 fran  staff  9016705024 Sep 24 22:06 Ubuntu.vdi
-rw-------+ 1 fran  staff        8317 Sep 24 22:06 Ubuntu.vbox
~/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu:
```

Is it enough to share the Ubuntu.vdi file?

Comment: You could export the VM as a .ovf file, and then your friends can import it. https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-export

Answer (score 5):

VirtualBox can export VMs to a compressed archive using .ovf format. Your friends can then import the VM on their machines. There are two ways to do this, cli, and gui.

## The GUI Way:

[image: Slide Show Of Process]
[View Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgSRE.gif)

**To Export:**

1. In VirtualBox go to "File/Export Appliance".
2. Choose the VM you want to export.
3. Choose a location to save the .ovf file to, and which version of ovf to use.
4. Fill in any desire information (eg: vm name, product, and other relevant information).
5. Wait for it to export.

**To Import:**

1. In VirtualBox go to "File/Import Appliance".
2. Choose the .ovf file you wish to import.
3. If desired you'll be able to change VM settings, and re-initialze the mac-addresses.
4. Wait for it to import.

Comment: which version of ovf should I use? I am using the latest version of virtualbox.

Comment: @user3111525 As long as your friends are running a recent version of VirtualBox too, then you can use version 2.0 ovf.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox has a feature designed for exactly what you're wanting to do.  From the VirtualBox Manager, select from "Export Appliance" the "File" menu.  You should be able to share the resulting `.ova` file with your colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

You could, but then every machine will have the same hostname and will need configuring on every Mac. On first install, I recommend you should boot them separately and give them separate host names.